# Duplicate keys detected: 'X'. This may cause an update error. in VueJS datatable search

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, duplicates

In my laravel vue application I have following datatable with some filters in a vue component(department-user-list.vue).

```
<template>
    <div>
        <cs-card
            :cardButton="false"
            :title="`Team members`"
        >
            <template slot="header-action">
                <div class="inline-block mr-4" direction-from="top">
                    <open-overlay identifier="corporateInviteEmployeeToDepartmentModal">
                        <cs-button size="small" variant="secondary">
                            Invite team member
                        </cs-button>
                    </open-overlay>
                </div>
                <div class="inline-block" direction-from="top">
                    <cs-button @click="redirectToAssignation" size="small">
                        Assign team member
                    </cs-button>
                </div>
            </template>
            <Datatable
                v-model="selectedForAction"
                :data="dataset"
                :headers="headers"
                :is-loading="isLoading"
                :has-action-bar-column="true"
                :key-id="`id`"
                :search-panel="{placeholder: 'Search team member...'}"
                @change="handlePaginationChange"
                @paginate="loadDepartmentEmployees"
            >
                <!--Filter Slot-->
                <template v-slot:filters>
                    <!--Nationality filter-->
                    <div class="w-2/12 pl-4 h-auto">
                        <cs-multiple-select
                            v-model="nationalitiesFilter"
                            :options="countries"
                            key-id="id"
                            label="name"
                            name="nationality"
                            placeholder="Nationality"
                        >
                        </cs-multiple-select>
                    </div>
                    <!--Certificate Status filter-->
                    <div class="w-6/12 pl-4 h-auto">
                        <cs-multiple-select
                            v-model="certificateStatusFilter"
                            :options="certificateStatus"
                            name="certificateStatusFilter"
                            placeholder="Qualification status"
                            @input="loadDepartmentEmployees"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <!--Matrix Status filter-->
                    <div class="w-4/12 pl-4 h-auto">
                        <cs-multiple-select
                            v-model="matrixStatusFilter"
                            :options="matrixStatus"
                            key-id="value"
                            label="label"
                            name="matrixStatusFilter"
                            placeholder="Matrix status"
                            @input="loadDepartmentEmployees"
                        />
                    </div>
                     <!--Employee Type  filter-->
                        <div class="w-4/12 pl-4 h-auto">
                            <cs-multiple-select
                                v-model="selectedEmployeeTypes"
                                :options="employeeType"
                                key-id="value"
                                label="label"
                                name="selectedEmployeeTypes"
                                placeholder="Employee type"
                                @input="loadDepartmentEmployees"
                            >
                            </cs-multiple-select>
                        </div>
                </template>

                <!--Table Header-->
                <template v-slot:header.country="{ header}">
                    <span class="material-icons-outlined">language</span>
                </template>

                <!--Table Body-->
                <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
                    <div class="flex items-center cursor-pointer">
                        <div class="rounded-full w-8 h-8 mr-4 overflow-hidden">
                            <img :src="item.profile_image[0].url" alt=""
                                 class="w-full h-full object-cover">
                        </div>
                        <a :href="employeeDetailRoute(item)">
                            <span class="text-certstyle-titles font-bold leading-loose">{{ item.name }}</span>
                        </a>
                        <span
                            v-if="item.is_subcontractor && item.company_name"
                            :title="item.company_name"
                            class="text-certstyle-text-light bg-certstyle-background flex font-semibold cursor-help  text-xs rounded mx-2 py-1 px-2"
                        >
                            {{ item.company_name.substring(0,10) }}
                             <span v-if="item.company_name.length > 10">...</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:item.job_title="{ item }">
                    {{ item.current_jobtitle || item.department_jobtitle }}
                </template>
                <template v-slot:item.country="{ item }">
                <span v-if="item.country" class="font-normal">
                    <country-flag width="w-5" :country-code="item.country.country_code"></country-flag>
                </span>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:item.certificate_status="{ item }">
                    <div class="status--summary--component inline-block mr-2 relative"
                         @click="getValidityStatus(item.certificate_matrix) !== 'all valid' &&
                            getValidityStatus(item.certificate_matrix) !== '-'
                             ? openCertificatesModal(item) : null
                         ">
                        <label :class="getValidityStatusClass(item.certificate_matrix)" class="badge">
                            {{ getValidityStatus(item.certificate_matrix) }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:item.matrix_status="{ item }">
                    <div class="status--summary--component inline-block mr-2 relative"
                         @click="getMatrixStatus(item.certificate_matrix) === 'non compliant'
                            ? openCertificatesModal(item)
                            : null
                         ">
                        <label :class="getMatrixStatusClass(item.certificate_matrix)" class="badge">
                            {{ getMatrixStatus(item.certificate_matrix) }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:actionItems="slotProps">
                    <DatatableActionbarItem
                        :slot-props="slotProps"
                        identifier="removeConfirmationModal"
                        label="Remove"
                        variant="danger"
                    />
                </template>
                <template v-slot:rowActionItems="slotProps">
                    <DatatableActionbarItem
                        icon=""
                        label="Contact details"
                        @click.native="openContactDetailsModal(slotProps.item)"
                        :slot-props="slotProps"
                    />
                </template>
            </Datatable>


            <modal-md
                v-if="selectedEmployee !== null"
                :options="{ useDefaultContentStyling: false }"
                      :identifier="`statusSummaryComponent`">
                <template slot="modal_title">
                    Qualifications
                    <span v-if="selectedEmployee !== null && selectedEmployee !== undefined">
                            {{ selectedEmployee.name }}
                        </span>
                </template>


                <div class="bg-white" slot="modal_content">
                    <div
                        class="flex items-center justify-between text-certstyle-text-light bg-white border-certstyle-border border-b text-sm py-2 px-10">
                        <cs-dashboard-table-header-item-unstyled :item="`statusSummaryCertificateTitle`">
                            <p>Qualification</p>
                        </cs-dashboard-table-header-item-unstyled>

                        <cs-dashboard-table-header-item-unstyled :item="`statusSummaryCertificateStatus`">
                            <p>Validity Status</p>
                        </cs-dashboard-table-header-item-unstyled>

                        <cs-dashboard-table-header-item-unstyled :item="`statusSummaryMatrixStatus`">
                            <p>Matrix Status</p>
                        </cs-dashboard-table-header-item-unstyled>

                    </div>

                    <!--Certificates-->
                    <div class="text-certstyle-titles">
                        <div v-for="certificate in selectedEmployee.certificate_matrix"
                             v-if="selectedEmployee.certificate_matrix.length > 0"
                             class="table--row flex items-center justify-between border-certstyle-border last:border-b-0 border-b px-10 py-4">
                            <!-- Title -->
                            <cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled
                                class="w-1/2"
                                :item="`statusSummaryCertificateTitle`">
                                <p :title="certificate.title" class=" ">
                                    {{ certificate.title | limitString(30, '...') }}
                                </p>
                            </cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled>

                            <cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled class="w-32" :item="`statusSummaryCertificateStatus`">
                                <div class="flex items-center justify-start w-full">
                                    <!--Expired styling-->
                                    <label v-if="certificate.matrix_status === 0"
                                           class="badge badge-danger">
                                        -
                                    </label>

                                    <!--Expires styling-->
                                    <label v-if="certificate.matrix_status &&  certificate.expired === 1"
                                           class="badge badge-danger">
                                        expired
                                    </label>
                                    <!--Expires styling-->
                                    <label v-if="certificate.matrix_status &&  certificate.expire_soon === 1"
                                           class="badge badge-danger">
                                        expires soon
                                    </label>

                                    <!--Active styling-->
                                    <label
                                        v-if="certificate.matrix_status &&  certificate.expire_soon === 0 && certificate.expired === 0"
                                        class="badge badge-success">
                                        active
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled>

                            <cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled
                                class="w-32"
                                :item="`statusSummaryMatrixStatus`">
                                <!--Active styling-->
                                <label v-if="certificate.matrix_status"
                                       class="badge badge-success">
                                    compliant
                                </label>
                                <label v-else
                                       class="badge badge-danger">
                                    non-compliant
                                </label>
                            </cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled>
                        </div>
                        <div v-else
                             class="table--row flex items-center justify-between border-certstyle-border last:border-b-0 border-b px-10 py-4">
                            <cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled
                                class="w-1/2"
                                :item="`statusSummaryCertificateTitle`">
                                No certificates found
                            </cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled>
                            <cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled class="w-32"
                                                              :item="`statusSummaryCertificateStatus`">
                            </cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled>
                            <cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled
                                class="w-32"
                                :item="`statusSummaryMatrixStatus`">
                            </cs-dashboard-table-item-unstyled>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </modal-md>
        </cs-card>

        <contact-details
            v-if="userToShowContactDetails"
            :user="userToShowContactDetails"
        />

        <add-employee-modal
            :countries="countries"
            :identifier="`addEmployeeModal`"
            :invite-modal-title="`Invite to department`"
            :suggestion-url="userSuggestionApiURL"
            :title="`Assign to ${department ? department.name: ''}`"
            @inviteEmployees="handleInvitedEmployees"
            @selectEmployee="addEmployeeToDepartment"
            @removeEmployee="handleRemoveEmployee"
        />

        <cs-confirmation-modal
            v-if="checkRole(['admin', 'planner'])"
            @proceed="handleRemoveEmployee"
            identifier="removeConfirmationModal">
            <div class="text-certstyle-titles font-normal" slot="content">
                Removing employees from this department can not be undo.
            </div>

            <div slot="cancelButton"
                 class="cursor-pointer hover:bg-certstyle-background border border-certstyle-border rounded px-6 py-2 text-certstyle-text-light mr-4">
                Cancel
            </div>

            <cs-button slot="proceedButton">
                Remove
            </cs-button>
        </cs-confirmation-modal>
    </div>

</template>
```

This list and the filters works fine but when I try to search a user by typing their names, it kept giving me following error,

> Duplicate keys detected: '1025'. This may cause an update error.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at resources/js/components/reusable/datatable/Datatable.vue
>  at resources/js/components/reusable/csCard.vue
>  at resources/js/components/dashboard/communities/department/one-departments/department-user-list.vue

But when I try to filter the list by some other param, they get filtered without any error.

I'm struggling to find what I'm doing wrong here....

**UPDATE**

following is my non-filtered json data for a single user

```
 {
      "id": 1038,
      "unique_id": "0a3938c1-07d5-3884-9df0-a8fe3201a3e5",
      "first_name": "Mango",
      "last_name": "F1",
      "job_title": null,
      "email": "mangoF1@gmail.com",
      "phone_number": null,
      "phone_country_calling_code": null,
      "country_id": null,
      "company_name": null,
      "is_subcontractor": 0,
      "current_jobtitle": "Deck Foreman",
      "department_jobtitle": "Rigging Engineers",
      "language": "en",
      "email_verified_at": "2022-04-12T12:47:55.000000Z",
      "gender": null,
      "state": null,
      "postal_code": null,
      "house_number": null,
      "street": null,
      "city": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "city_of_birth": null,
      "emergency_number": null,
      "opt_in": null,
      "created_at": "2022-04-12T12:46:34.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-04-12T12:47:55.000000Z",
      "emergency_number_country_calling_code": null,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "has_ip_restriction": 0,
      "address": null,
      "latitude": null,
      "longitude": null,
      "place_id": null,
      "bouwpas_worker_id": null,
      "bouwpas_certificate_id": null,
      "certificate_matrix": [
        {
          "id": 463,
          .....
        }
      ]
    },
```

Following is my controller function,

```
public function index($locale, Company $company, Department $department, Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('viewUsers', [Department::class, $company, $department]);

        $users = $department->usersWithSubcontractors()
            //            ->notApiUser()
            ->select(
                'users.id',
                'unique_id',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'job_title',
                'email',
                'phone_number',
                'unique_id',
                'phone_country_calling_code',
                'country_id',
                'company_name',
                'is_subcontractor',
            )->addSelect([
                'current_jobtitle' => JobTitle::selectRaw('IFNULL(project_specific_job_titles.title, job_titles.title)')
                    ->join('project_track_records', 'project_track_records.user_id', 'users.id', 'inner')
                    ->join('project_specific_job_titles', 'project_track_records.project_specific_job_title_id', 'project_specific_job_titles.id', 'inner')
                    ->whereColumn('job_titles.id', 'project_specific_job_titles.job_title_id')
                    ->whereDate('project_track_records.start_date', '<=', Carbon::now())
                    ->whereDate('project_track_records.end_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
                    ->limit(1),
                'department_jobtitle' => JobTitle::selectRaw('title')->whereColumn('job_titles.id', 'department_user.job_title_id'),
            ])->when(request('q'), function ($q) {
                $q->where(function ($q) {
                    $q->whereRaw("CONCAT_WS(' ', `first_name`, `last_name`) like '%" . request('q') . "%'");
                });
            })->when($request->get('employeeType'), function ($q) use ($request) {
                $q->whereIn('users.is_subcontractor', $request->get('employeeType'));
            })->paginate(\request('per_page', config('repository.pagination.limit')));

        $users->load('country');
        $users->append(['profile_image']);
        $users->makeVisible(['unique_id']);

        $users->map(fn ($item) => $item->certificate_matrix = (new GetCertificationMatrixQueryAction())->execute($item->id, $department->id));

        if ($request->filled('certificateStatus')) {
            $valid = in_array('valid', $request->get('certificateStatus'));
            $expire_soon = in_array('expire soon', $request->get('certificateStatus'));
            $expired = in_array('expired', $request->get('certificateStatus'));

            if ($valid) $users->setCollection($users->filter(fn ($item) => $item->certificate_matrix->filter(fn ($certificate) => $certificate->matrix_status && !$certificate->expire_soon && !$certificate->expired)->count() === $item->certificate_matrix->count())->values());
            if ($expire_soon && !$expired) $users->setCollection($users->filter(fn ($item) => $item->certificate_matrix->filter(fn ($certificate) => $certificate->matrix_status && $certificate->expire_soon)->count() > 0)->values());
            if ($expired && !$expire_soon) $users->setCollection($users->filter(fn ($item) => $item->certificate_matrix->filter(fn ($certificate) => $certificate->matrix_status && $certificate->expired)->count() > 0)->values());
        }

        if ($request->filled('matrixStatus')) {
            $compliant = in_array('compliant', $request->get('matrixStatus'));
            $non_compliant = in_array('non-compliant', $request->get('matrixStatus'));

            if ($non_compliant && !$compliant)
                $users->setCollection($users->filter(fn ($item) => $item->certificate_matrix->filter(fn ($certificate) => $certificate->matrix_status === 0 || $certificate->expire_soon || !$certificate->expired)->count() > 0)->values());

            if ($compliant && !$non_compliant)
                $users->setCollection($users->filter(fn ($item) => $item->certificate_matrix->filter(fn ($certificate) => $certificate->matrix_status && !$certificate->expire_soon && !$certificate->expired)->count() == $item->certificate_matrix->count())->values());
        }
        return response()->json($users);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your `dataset` ?

Comment: question updated

Comment: It seems like you have duplicates in the dataset. Try debuging the data from the dataset with the key `1025` (`dataset.filter(x => x.id === 1025`) and check if there is more than one record

Comment: thank you for the valuable idea, but there were no duplicate users under id 1025

Comment: Can you show only ids instead of the all datasets ? like `dataset.map(item => {return {id: item.id, certificate_matrix: item.certificate_matrix.map(x => x.id)}})
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample data for single user has duplicate `id` values in `certificate_matrix` array (2nd and 11th record both have id of 443)

This would probably be causing an issue in the `v-for` loop at (where you do not have any `:key` actually)

```html
<!--Certificates-->
<div class="text-certstyle-titles">
    <div v-for="certificate in selectedEmployee.certificate_matrix"
         v-if="selectedEmployee.certificate_matrix.length > 0"
         class="table--row flex items-center justify-between border-certstyle-border last:border-b-0 border-b px-10 py-4">
```

Or at any other place where `certificate_matrix` records are being looped over

###### Using composite key combining value of two fields to generate unique key

One way to try to ensure unique keys on frontend is to have a combination (kind of like composite key index) as `${id}-${matrix_status}` if that combination is to remain unique.

###### Using loop iteration index as composite suffix to generate unique key

If there is no other field value which can be combined to ensure **unique** keys for child nodes within `v-for` then the `${id}-${index}` can be used to generate unique keys - eg:

```
<div v-for="(certificate, index) in selectedEmployee.certificate_matrix"
     :key="`${certificate.id}-${index}`" //To ensure uniqueness of key
     v-if="selectedEmployee.certificate_matrix.length > 0"
     class="table--row flex items-center justify-between border-certstyle-border last:border-b-0 border-b px-10 py-4">
```

###### Using uuid as unique key

Another way is to add a `uuid` column on the database tables and then use the `uuid` as key in the `<DataTable />` component markup including subcomponents where `:key` or `:key-id` are used.

Laravel makes it very easy to generate Uuid v4 - uuids via `(string) Str::orderedUuid();` And also has `$table->uuid('uid')->index()` column type for migration files.

Can even have `uid` stored when a new model record is being created/persisted

```php
// In any model class which has a uuid column
public static function booted()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->uid = Str::orderedUuid()->toString();
    });
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Helpers - Str Ordered Uuid](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-ordered-uuid)

[Laravel Docs - Migrations - Uuid Column Type](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-uuid)

[Laravel Docs - Uuid - Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-uuid)

#### Update

Based on feedback via comment

> Thank you for your answer, I have updated the question with the correct backend controller. The reason for id duplication is one user can have multiple departments. Because of that my eloquent gives me results with multiple user id's for some results. When I tried to group the results by user.id, it gives me an 500 error, and I need to pass the user.id as the key rather than passing uuid since the id has used for other functions, like user deletion and all... Any way to group the result from the backend to get only unique user ids?

To ensure only **unique** user records being sent via response from the controller, filter out duplicate records for the `$users` collection via `unique()` method available on `Collection`

```
//...method code
$users->setCollection($users->unique('id')->values());

return response()->json($users);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated the question with the correct backend controller. The reason for id duplication is one user can have multiple departments. Because of that my eloquent gives me results with multiple user id's for some results. When I tried to group the results by user.id, it gives me an 500 error, and I need to pass the user.id as the key rather than passing uuid since the id has used for other functions, like user deletion and all... Any way to group the result from the backend to get only unique user ids?

Comment: Just before `return response()` line can you do `$users->setCollection($users->unique('id')->values())`?

Comment: Uuid use is indicated just for Vue to keep track of the nodes within `v-for` loop. You may still pass the user.id to the child components. However, if don't want to have uuid, doesn't a composite key like `${user.id}-${index}` work for you? This key is just so that vue can uniquely identify child nodes in a `v-for`. It's not like passing it as prop to any child component.

Comment: $users->setCollection($users->unique('id')->values()) this has worked!!! please add this in your answer since I've marked it as accepted one. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that you have duplicates and you are confused about the reason of getting such an error message, when the `id` of the user is unique (probably a `primary key`). However, it is important to note that you load your users with departments and if a user has multiple departments, then you will get that user multiple times. You can group the results to solve the issue.

Comment: tried groupBy('id'), still getting the same error though..